# Why we are not able to use getOut() of exchange in case of changing filename?

Tags: apache-camel

Why are we not able to use **getOut : Message-Exchange** here down in this code to change file name by using camel apache:

```
String origFileName = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader(exchange.FILE_NAME_CONSUMED);
System.out.println(origFileName);
exchange.getIn().removeHeader(Exchange.OVERRULE_FILE_NAME);
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,"newFileName.xml");
```

Answer (score 3):

See this FAQ which explains about IN vs OUT and what you should favor use
http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Comment: what about camel 3.5 where all getOut methods are deprecated? the getMessage() changes the getIn body as well.

Comment: https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-api/3.0.0-RC2/deprecated-list.html
seems like we should use `getMessage()` instead of `getOut()`